# Multi conexões MySQL Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

No meu database.php criei duas conexões:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; 
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'sitejc';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['date_default_timezone_set'] = 'America/Sao_Paulo';

$db['parceiro']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; 
$db['parceiro']['username'] = 'root';
$db['parceiro']['password'] = '';
$db['parceiro']['database'] = 'sistema2';
$db['parceiro']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['parceiro']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['parceiro']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['parceiro']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['parceiro']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['parceiro']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['parceiro']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['parceiro']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['parceiro']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['parceiro']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['parceiro']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['parceiro']['date_default_timezone_set'] = 'America/Sao_Paulo';

/* End of file database.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/database.php */
```

Dentro do meu controller, dei um load dessa forma:

```
$parceiro_db = $this->load->database('parceiro', TRUE);
```

Porém, ao efetuar uma requisição do banco de dados selecionado me retorna erro.

Forma de requisição:

```
class Cadastro extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_cadastro');
        $parceiro = $this->load->database('parceiro', TRUE);
    }

    # Cadastro para Empresa
    public function empresa($metodo=NULL) {
        if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $clientes = $parceiro->get('cliente')->result();
        }
```

Erro:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   /home/jcentreg/public_html/sitejc/site/modules/cadastro/controllers/cadastro.php
>   on line 21

Como eu faço esta multi conexão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não seria `$parceiro_db`?

```
$clientes = $parceiro_db->get('clientes')->result();
```

[***Doc - Connecting to Multiple Databases***](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases)

Para funcionar existe um problema na configuração no `$db['parceiro']['dbdriver']` está setado como `mysql` coloque no lugar `mysqli`:

```
$db['parceiro']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; 
$db['parceiro']['username'] = 'root';
$db['parceiro']['password'] = '';
$db['parceiro']['database'] = 'sistema2';
$db['parceiro']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['parceiro']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['parceiro']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['parceiro']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['parceiro']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['parceiro']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['parceiro']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['parceiro']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['parceiro']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['parceiro']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['parceiro']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['parceiro']['date_default_timezone_set'] = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
```

---

```
$db = $this->load->database("parceiro", TRUE);
var_dump(  $db->get("cliente")->result_array() );
```

---

***Erro de codificação:***

```
class Cadastro extends MY_Controller 
{
    private $parceiro;
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_cadastro');
        $this->parceiro = $this->load->database('parceiro', TRUE);
    }

    # Cadastro para Empresa
    public function empresa($metodo=NULL) 
    {
        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
            $clientes = $this->parceiro->get('cliente')->result();
        }
```

Como foi utilizado uma variável para funcionar nos métodos tem que utilizar `$this` para atribuir e utilizar.

***Exemplos:*** [*SOEn* - **CodeIgniter: Multiple Databases - Accessing database config in a second database**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348423/codeigniter-multiple-databases-accessing-database-config-in-a-second-database)

Comment: Se eu chamar o ->db-> ele busca o db atual, eu tenho outro db na conexão, por isso, chamei de parceiro

Comment: @AndréBaill, então refiz a edição.! olha como seria!

Comment: Load: $parceiro = $this->load->database('parceiro', TRUE); - chamei assim: $clientes = $parceiro->get('clientes')->result();, retorno Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in D:\Sites\Localhost\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\jcentregasrapidas\site\modules\cadastro\controllers\cadastro.php on line 18

Comment: @AndréBaill no seu arquivo database.php, poste completinho na sua pergunta! acho que está errado, por favor, edite a sua questão e coloque ela completa!

Comment: Editei, dá uma olhadinha

Comment: @AndréBaill tem um erro de configuração, ou então versão de `PHP` que não está configurado, então coloque o que eu disse na resposta e teste! use sempre `mysqli` para `PHP`

Comment: Então, eu fiz o $this->db->get('x')->result(), e e ele vem, mas na documentação diz que eu tenho que chamar da variavel que eu coloquei de conexão...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46307/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-andre-baill).

Comment: @AndréBaill entra no chat, porque, você está todo confuso, o que eu fiz é o correto... olha `$db` é uma variavel que recebe as configurações de conexão.